# Не работают некоторые сочетания клавиш в консоли FreeBSD

Tags: консоль, shell, freebsd

Я зашёл по ssh на сервер, на котором установлена ОС FreeBSD *(например, на хостинге nic.ru установлена FreeBSD 8.1),* и при работе в консоли обнаружил, что некоторые привычные сочетания клавиш (например, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>стрелка вправо/влево</kbd> для "перепрыгивания" между словами) не работают. Вместо ожидаемого действия я получаю в консоль мусорный вывод такого вида:

```
;5D;5D;5C;5C~~
```

Как заставить работать сочетания клавиш, которые не работают в консоли FreeBSD "из коробки"?

Comment: А чем именно Вы туда зашли? с putty под виндой или правильного терминала с линукса, или может терминалом с белоснежного-ненужного мака?

Comment: Воспроизводится и в Linux-xterm-подобном-терминале, и в putty-из-под-windows. В MacOS не проверял, но, подозреваю, воспроизведется так же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в ненастроенном `readline(3)`. "Мусор", который видно в терминале - это коды нажатия клавиш и их сочетаний, которым не присвоены никакие функции (чтобы увидеть коды для сочетаний клавиш, которым функции присвоены, можно нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> и потом интересующее сочетание клавиш (или единичную клавишу) - для кнопки <kbd>Enter</kbd>, например, код будет `^M` - то есть вместо <kbd>Enter</kbd> в консоли можно нажимать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> с тем же эффектом, сюрприз!). Уже назначенные на разные клавиши и их сочетания функции можно посмотреть командой `bind -lpvs`.

Для `sh` и `bash` настройки `readline` можно задать в файле `.inputrc` в домашней папке пользователя. Для реализации неработающих из коробки в FreeBSD сочетаний клавиш я использую следующие настройки:

```
# ~/.inputrc: readline initialization file.
# (you can view all current assignments by runnig `bind -lpvs`)

# let Insert, PageUP, PageDown keys work properly in bash under FreeBSD and Linux:
"\e[2~": overwrite-mode
"\e[5~": beginning-of-history
"\e[6~": end-of-history

# let Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow jump over words:
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\eOC": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\eOD": backward-word
```

Стоит отметить, что код сочетания клавиш, который можно прочесть с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, может отличаться для разных видов терминалов - например, не совпадать в "обычном" терминале и внутри `screen`. Вы можете самостоятельно расширить предлагаемый `~/.inputrc` для таких случаев.